# Cannot open file 'sfml-system-d.lib' - C++

Tags: c++

First off, I understand the inconveniences that may come with asking this kind of question and would like to at least state that for a *relatively* experienced C++ console programmer learning *GUI in C++* is tasking compared to other languages like *Java* and *Python* (then again, what isn't tasking?).

Anyways, before I ramble on. The question (problem that needs a solution) is how do I get my template SFML program (https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-vc.php) working in Visual Studio when I receive this error message in the console:

> **LNK1104** cannot open file *'sfml-system-d.lib'*

I've followed multiple tutorials about a dozen times now leading to more frustration with this minor challenge each time I get this exact reason my first SFML program not working.

I've searched for the file `sfml-system-d.lib` as well and found absolutely nothing.

I'm using **SFML v2.4.0** for **Windows 32-Bit applications** and also using **MinGW's GCC v6.3.0** to compile my C++ console programs.

For additional references, here's what I got so far:

[image]

**GitHub Repository - https://github.com/LapysDev/Learn/tree/master/C%2B%2B/GUI/sfml-visual%20studio/demo.v2**

I know this question is off the mark here and I fully expect to be put in my place.

Anyways, thanks for reading through this far; And again my apologies for taking up anyone's time.

Comment: Have you checked all the common causes listed on the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=vs-2017 ? In most cases the problem is that the linker path is wrong

Comment: First step, throw the error message at a search engine and do some research what can cause it and how to fix it. That said, the `-d` suggests a debug version, so mayme you just need to install it?

Comment: Few things you might want to check: 1) the path to the library 2) Is the library 32 bit and you are compiling 64 bit 3) Do you have read permission to the path you added.

Comment: looks like a permissions error

Comment: @UnholySheep: Yes, definitely I've seen the online document and I'm still reading through again to make sense of the error.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: That led to a entire search result page of already visited links with related but not accurate enough answers. But you may be onto something with the installation there. Could you extrapolate, please?

Comment: @macroland: As far as I understand, I downloaded **SFML v2.4.0 for 32-Bit Windows applications** and created a new project in Visual Studio called **Windows Console Application**. More than that, I am honestly unfamiliar with compilation based on system-architectures.

Comment: "I've searched for the file sfml-system-d.lib as well and found absolutely nothing." -- what isn't there, can't be linked. So your question boils down to where to get this file. It might also be useful to look at the files that you downloaded and installed, just to get an overview. Then, also check whether a 32-bit application is being built, because most computers today use 64 bit CPUs.